# jquery sibling selector in a different div

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, siblings

I'm new to jquery and trying to make this code work that users have helped me with but I'm now having trouble.

I want to have my photography website have buttons at the top and when you click a button, the category that you click (ie. 'landscapes' 'portraits' 'weddings') show all of the posts with those "tags" (div classes).  I have it working in a fiddle but when I try to wrap divs around the post and buttons to position them on the page, the sibling selector breaks.

**Older working** fiddle here (no div wrappers):    http://jsfiddle.net/PxpXy/

**The broken fiddle here** (with div wrappers):     http://jsfiddle.net/JUsZK/10/

I have added wrappers to both the buttons at the top and the context (#test & #test2)  but now (obviously) the siblings selector does not work.

How can I still have my site function and use div wrappers to reposition them on the page?  Would I no longer want the sibling selector?

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider posting the relevant parts of both code fragments in your question (or a single version of the code with revisions marked up with comments). Fiddles are a good idea, but Stack Overflow aims to be self-contained, and if (`$DEITY` forbid) jsfiddle goes offline somewhere down the line, your question would be left orphaned and not of much use for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Given you've wrapped the pictures in a div with id "test" you can do this:

```
$('#test .post').hide();
```

That is, hide elements with class '.post' that are inside the '#test' div.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/JUsZK/12/

Comment: Thank you!  That rocks.  Super easy, too

Answer (score 2):

Your divs are not sibblings anylonger, a fixed version could be http://jsfiddle.net/JUsZK/11/

Comment: Thanks.  I also liked this fix!

Answer (score 2):

You have to simply amend your selector to:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div.post').hide()
    $('.' + this.id).show(500);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JUsZK/13/).

Using `$('div.post')` will, of course, work on *all* `div` elements with the `class` of `post`. To restrict responses to only *certain* `div`s, you could specify a parent container element, and then use `find()` to work with only those elements in which you're specifically interested, for example:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(parentElementSelector).find('.post').hide()
    $('.' + this.id).show(500);
});
```

Note that I haven't corrected the multiple-`id` problem, but I'd suggest using a `class` (or, since you're not using it in the jQuery I could *see* in your problem, simply removing the `id`).

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'll have a look at your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, `id`s should be unique.  In your second (non-working) fiddle, you have three divs with the id `test`.

Comment: That may be true in a general sense, but it's not why the jQuery code didn't work in the second fiddle.